# Magento 1.9.3.8: How many cache records can the default zend_cache handle?

Tags: magento-1.9

I recently checked my cache size in Magento 1.9.3.8 and noticed a high number of cache records. I decided to completely flush the cache storage to monitor the cache.

- After 24hrs the cache has about 4500 records and a size of 206M
- After 48hrs the cache has about 6500 records and a size of 332M

I guess the size of the cache will now grow slower as time goes on but I'm still wondering how many records the default zend_cache of M1 can handle.

I have about 5000 products with 1 store view. Are the records/size normal for this kind of shop?

Thank you